# How to turn a macro's name into literal string, when the macro is inside an struct array?

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor, x-macros

say I have the following

```
#define STR(x) #x
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2

typedef struct
{
    int item;
    char * name;
}bag_t;

bag_t my_bag[] = 
{
    {ONE, ""};
    {TWO, ""};
}
```

I want to add the name of the macro to the name variable so something like this:

```
my_bag[1].name = STR(my_bag[1].item);
```

That obviously doesn't work since it not expanded. How can workaround this?

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using enums? Then the STR macro would work as you want it to.

Comment: What you’re after goes by the name “X macros”, sometimes hyphenated.  There is even a tag [tag:x-macros] for the topic. I doubt that every question about X macros has been tagged with it, but it gives you a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is 100% what you want, but perhaps it's close enough:

```
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2

typedef struct
{
    int item;
    const char *name;
}bag_t;

#define BAG_INIT(n) { n, #n }

const bag_t my_bag[] = 
{
    BAG_INIT(ONE),
    BAG_INIT(TWO),
};

int main(void) {
    printf("name of %d is '%s'\n", my_bag[0].item, my_bag[0].name);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
name of 1 is 'ONE'
```